# Using rb_require with rb_protect to embed Ruby in C

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I want to use rb_require with rb_protect, as in the following example:

```
int error;
rb_protect( (VALUE (*)(VALUE))rb_require, (VALUE) "./test", &error);
```

But when I compile it, I get this error:

```
passing argument 1 of ‘rb_protect’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:357:7: note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE)’ but argument is of type ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE,  VALUE)’
```

After searching on Google to see how to use rb_require with rb_protect, I tried:

```
int error;
rb_protect( RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(rb_require), (VALUE) "./test", &error);
```

or

```
VALUE require_wrap(VALUE arg)
{
return rb_require("./test");
}
/*in main:*/
rb_protect( require_wrap, 0, & error);
```

But I always get the same error. This error doesn't stop the compilation but the binary segfault when I launch it whereas everything works without the rb_protect.

**__*Edit*__**

there was an error in my source file. In fact all the solutions I have tested works well:

```
int error;
rb_protect( (VALUE (*)(VALUE))rb_require, (VALUE) "./test", &error);
```

or

```
int error;
rb_protect( RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(rb_require), (VALUE) "./test", &error);
```

or

```
VALUE require_wrap(VALUE arg)
{
  return rb_require("./test");
}
/*in main:*/
rb_protect( require_wrap, 0, & error);
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't help you with this problem, but you might find this [list](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-c-api/info) of resources helpful.

Comment: thanks for this list but I have already read a lot of those documentation. I wrote a module, some class and method for testing purpose. But now I want to be able to handle errors in the ruby file that I load in the embeded interpreter. The first code come from an official documentation but it doesn't works.

Comment: And this will not work? `rb_protect( rb_require, rb_str_new2("./test"), &error);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions that works well:

```
int error;
rb_protect( (VALUE (*)(VALUE))rb_require, (VALUE) "./test", &error);
```

or

```
int error;
rb_protect( RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(rb_require), (VALUE) "./test", &error);
```

or

```
VALUE require_wrap(VALUE arg)
{
  return rb_require("./test");
}
/*in main:*/
rb_protect( require_wrap, 0, & error);
```